# Java string loop stops after digit

Tags: java, string, loops, substring

I'm doing a simple excercise for fun. I take a string and get the longest substring that has:

```
1. At least one upper case character.
2. No digits.
```

However when I loop like follows over substring "a0Ba":

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

        if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))) {
            substring += s.charAt(i);
        }
        else {
            arr.add(substring);
            substring = "";
        }
}
```

It seems to stop at the zero and not continue. Even though a valid substring "Ba" comes right after.

When I runs with this substring: "AsdF0ASDFGffdfr09asd0sd0sd0e"

It works fine and dandy and returns the correct substring: "ASDFGffdfr"

Why is this? I am so confused

Comment: Can you put this in a form of a [MCVE]? How are you getting the output? What is `arr`? etc

Comment: @LukasWiklund OP's question says that it works fine for that input. The problematic input is `"a0Ba"`

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ -- specifically, in this case, your program is short enough that you can manually (i.e. with pencil and paper) step through what it does with your failing input, and see for yourself what's wrong. "Rubber ducking" will probably help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens when the correct substring is at the end of the input, because you add a candidate to the list only when you see a digit.

Add a test for `substring` to be non-empty after the loop and add it to `arr` to fix the problem:

```
// The loop portion of your code remains unchanged:
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))) {
        substring += s.charAt(i);
    } else {
        arr.add(substring);
        substring = "";
    }
}
// Add this code to fix the problem:
if (!substring.isEmpty()) {
    arr.add(substring);
}
```